# Should I use $post = Timber::query_post() or $post = new TimberPost() in single wordpress template?

Tags: wordpress-theming, timber

I've read on the official Timber repository that general question about usage should be posted here.

I'm new to Timber/Twig and I have a a very "basic" question.

On the starter theme I've seen that in the `single.php` the $post variable that get passed to the $context is setted up with

```
$post = Timber::query_post()
```

while the `page.php` it is setted up with

```
$post = new TimberPost();
```

So, when I need to setup a single-cpt.php what method should I use? `Timber::query_post()` or `new TimberPost()`?

I've tried both of them and both of them are working, but what's the right way to do it?

Thanks!

PS: I've seen that in the `index.php` the `$context['post']` is being setup with `new Timber\PostQuery()`. Does this basically reproduce the standard loop of the template hierarchy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I understand there can be quite some confusion about which methods to use. Currently, there are a lot of ways to do it, and all that you’ve tried should work.

With the upcoming version 2 of Timber, we try to unify this and we will deprecate some of the methods that are still around. So, here’s how you should do it from now on.

---

**Update March 2020** – We’ve gone back and forth as to how the new API for 2.x should like and we’ve come up with a solution that is pretty much fixed. Some things will change there, you can check out this [pull request](https://github.com/timber/timber/pull/2073) if you want to learn more.

Until then, here’s our recommended way of doing things:

---

### Get a single post

```php
$post = new Timber\Post();
```

```php
$post = Timber::get_post();
```

### Get a collection of posts

```php
$post = new Timber\PostQuery();
```

```php
$post = Timber::get_posts();
```

If you want to use **pagination** with your posts, you will still have to use `Timber\PostQuery`:

```php
$post = new Timber\PostQuery();
```

(In Timber 2.x `Timber::get_posts()` will work with pagination, but not in 1.x yet.)

### The standard loop

> I've seen that in the index.php the $context['post'] is being setup with new Timber\PostQuery(). Does this basically reproduce the standard loop of the template hierarchy?

Yes!

In fact, if you don’t pass any arguments to `PostQuery()`, you don’t even have to set `$context['posts']`, because Timber [does that already for you in `Timber::get_context()`](https://github.com/timber/timber/blob/0d72eee300bf4e52ccb6aba34afa2eb4af6cf188/lib/Timber.php#L245).

**index.php**

```
<?php
use Timber\Timber;

$context = Timber::get_context();

Timber::render( 'index.twig', $context );
```

### Use namespaced class names

Currently, you might still see `TimberPost()` instead of `Timber\Post()`. For version 1, all Timber classes were namespaced, so the recommended way to do it from now is to **use the namespaced class names in PHP**, e.g. `Timber\Term` instead of `TimberTerm`.

**But!** In Twig, you’d still use the non-namespaced version:

```
{% set post = Post(post_id) %}
```

or

```
{% set post = TimberPost(post_id) %}
```

I hope this clears things up.

Comment: Thank you @Gchtr, your explanation was super clear! There's a small error in the sentence "the recommended way to do it from now is to use the namespaced class names in PHP, e.g. *Timber\Term instead of Timber\Term*". Thanks again :-)

Comment: You’re welcome! And thanks for pointing out the error, I just fixed that.

Comment: There is also the functions `Timber::get_posts` and `Timber::get_post`. How do they differ from initializing a timberpost or postquery object?

Comment: @IngóVals There’s not a real difference. `Timber::get_post()` and `Timber::get_posts` are aliases of `Timber::query_post()` and `Timber::query_posts()`. These 4 functions will be deprecated in version 2 in favor of `new Timber\Post()` and `new Timber\PostQuery()`.