# Timber: Single post pagination does not work (wp_link_pages)

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, timber

I am fairly new to Timber and I am trying to get the pagination for a single post item working. Since there are a lot of topics around the pagination for archives, I want to underline that this is about a single post pagination, that handles a multi-page single post created with `<!--nextpage-->` tags. In basic WordPress/PHP usage it is handled with [wp_link_pages()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_link_pages/) inside the loop.

As far as I understood, by searching SO and other websites, the magic should happen by just using the `post.pagination` array. But it's empty inside my twig file (and according to the Timber documentation does not exist at all inside the Timber\Post object).

My singular.php header looks like this:

```
$context     = Timber::get_context();
$post_object = new Timber\Post();
```

And here is my twig file:

```
{% if post.pagination %}

    <nav>Pages:

        {% for page in post.pagination.pages %}

            {% if page.current %}

                <span class="current">{{ page.title }}</span>{{ loop.last ? '' : ', ' }}

            {% else %}

                <a href="{{ page.link }}">{{ page.title }}</a>{{ loop.last ? '' : ', ' }}

            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}

    </nav>

{% endif %}
```

What am I doing wrong, what am I missing, how can I get the single post pagination to work with Timber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For single post pagination **to work Timber v1**, you need to use the older `Timber::query_post()` function instead of new `Timber::get_post()`.

```php
$context         = Timber::context();
$timber_post     = Timber::query_post(); // not Timber::get_post();
$context['post'] = $timber_post;
```

If you do this, then these should work as expected:

```php
{{ post.paged_content }}
```

Returns the content of the current page of a multi-page post. On a post without page breaks this will return the full content.

```php
{{ post.pagination }}
```

Returns a Timber/Pagination object for a multi-page post, or an empty array for a post without page breaks.

You don't need this, but it might be useful.

```php
if ( $multipage ) {
    $context['post']->post_content = $pages[$page - 1];
}
```

The point of this code would be to allow you to use `{{ post.content }}` instead of `{{ post.paged_content }}`.  Otherwise `{{ post.content }}` will return the whole post, even if there is pagination.

#### Note

This only applies to **Timber V1**. I have not experimented with **Timber V2**, because it is still being developed, but this issue is apparently fixed in that version, and `Timber::post_query` has been removed.

#### Reference:

- https://github.com/timber/timber/issues/1992#issuecomment-499718375
- [Should I use $post = Timber::query_post() or $post = new TimberPost() in single wordpress template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737508/should-i-use-post-timberquery-post-or-post-new-timberpost-in-single/48367651#48367651)

Answer (score 1):

To make `wp_link_pages()` work as you expect add these lines to your **singular.php**

```
global $post, $page, $pages, $multipage;
setup_postdata( $post );

// setting up your context
$context         = Timber::context();
$context['post'] = new Timber\Post();

if ( $multipage ) {
    $context['post']->post_content = $pages[$page - 1];
}
```

Then in your **twig** file instead of `post.content` you should write `post.paged_content` to get page content

Comment: I am building my theme with a boilerplate template that I got from a friend, which told me it works for him without your code.... Have to investigate if I screwed something up while modifying the boilerplate, but for now your solution is 100% working. Big thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not correctly added post to the context:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();

$post            = new Timber\Post();
$context['post'] = $post;
```

An additional tool is `{{ dump( post.pagination) }}`, when debuggin is enabled, which will print the output for a variable.